# $_SESSION['variable'] won't unset or change

Tags: session, authentication, usertype

```
$UserType = $row['UserType'];

$_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['UserID'];

//unset($_SESSION['UserType']);
$_SESSION['UserType'] = $UserType;
//unset($_SESSION['Dashboard']);
if ($UserType == 'read' OR 'edit' OR 'admin') {$_SESSION['Dashboard'] = 'YES';} 
else {$_SESSION['Dashboard']='NO';}

if ($_SESSION['Dashboard'] == 'YES') { ..... }
```

The else is not being reached.. Why please? Obviously I would also prefer TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
if ($UserType == 'read' OR 'edit' OR 'admin') {$_SESSION['Dashboard'] = 'YES';}
```

to

```
if ($UserType == 'read' OR $UserType =='edit' OR $UserType =='admin') {$_SESSION['Dashboard'] = 'YES';}
```

Comment: wow you are my saviour -- I always forget the fundamentals!! thank you very much Abderrahim

Comment: Welcome bro , please set my anwser as solution of your problem

Comment: I will do - but I have to wait another 7 minutes - thankssss

Comment: Take your time Bro ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is not correct. Current code is  basically comparing $UserType == 'ready' OR 'edit' is not 'empty', OR admin is not empty

You want:

if ($UserType == 'read' OR $UserType == 'edit' OR $UserType == 'admin')

Comment: that's right - I actually will make something that assigns the different user types to various different permissions also :) :) - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Run your check well

```
if ( ($UserType == 'read') OR ($UserType =='edit') OR ($UserType =='admin') ) {
$_SESSION['Dashboard'] = 'YES';
}else { 
$_SESSION['Dashboard']='NO';
}
```

Comment: yeh - basic grammar :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(